# Swift 4 Transfer results to main thread when using external networking framework

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4.2

I wanted to fetch data from the server api.
The issues is that all networking frameworks are doing it Async.
So I have issues that return variable return empty Here is my code.

The view controller where I call the function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = "http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?track_id=12693365&apikey=63ee7da5e2ee269067ecc42b25590922"

        let musixrequest = MusicMatchRequest()
        let endResults =  musixrequest.gettingLyrics(url: url)
        if !endResults.isEmpty{
            print("The end results are \(endResults)")
        }else{
            print("No results found")
        }


    }
```

Here is my class where I am trying to fetch the data

```
public class MusicMatchRequest : NSObject{

public override init(){}

 public func gettingLyrics(url : String) -> String {

    var endResults = ""

    DefaultProvider.request(Route(path:"\(url)")).responseJSON { (response:Response<Any>) in
        switch response.result{
        case .success(let json):
         endResults = String(describing:json)
            print(endResults)
          case .failure(let error):
            print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        return endResults
    }


}
```

When I am printing the endRsults from the task it is working It print the results but the var endResults return empty.
Idea how to transfer the data .

I have tried two frameworks

1. Alamofire
2. Nikka

In both frameworks it's acting the same .

Comment: You are missing the fact that your call is async. if you replace `return endResults` with `print("will return results"); return endResults` and ` endResults = String(describing:json)` with ` print("setting endResults); endResults = String(describing:json)` you'll see that the order of the print is not the one you think of. Look for "Swift + Async + Closure" to manage it.

Comment: Side note: `endResults = String(describing:json)` Don't. Just don't. Use/Parse real JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://gist.github.com/asos-bencepattogato/9a17396f00a2f6ce9d2eaa062384a2c1)
I don't exactly know what happens under the hood, but as ANY network operation this also has to be asynchronous (meaning it will take a certain amount of time to fetch the data).

`let endResults =  musixrequest.gettingLyrics(url: url)`

If it's synchronously done on the Main thread, it will block it so the user can't interact with the app, which is pretty bad. Given it's asynchronous in your code you read the value in the very next line immediately, here:

```
if !endResults.isEmpty {
    print("The end results are \(endResults)")
} else {
    print("No results found")
}
```

It's very unlikely that the network operation will finish in one line step time, so you won't have the data there.
What you should do is to pass a completion handler in this method:

`public func gettingLyrics(url : String) -> String`

and dispatch to main thread like this:

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
 // do you UI stuff here
}`

Change you function to this:

`public func gettingLyrics(url : String, completionHandler: (String) -> Void)`

and call the completion handler in the success branch:

`completionHandler(String(describing:json))`